# How to loop through all inputs inside a tr and set attribute(id and name) with

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

How to loop through all inputs inside a tr and set attribute(id and name) with JQuery

Answer (score 6):

```
$("tr input").each(function()
{
     $(this).attr("id", .....);
     $(this).attr("name", .....);
});
```

Comment: I know this is old, but I used this idea to loop through a tbody element and change names and IDs for multiple inputs on multiple rows.

Answer (score 3):

This could be done in one go:

```
$('tr input').attr({
    'id': 'new_id',
    'name': 'new_name'
});
```

But since id's are supposed to be unique this is probably not what you want to do. Here's a better approach:

```
$('tr input').attr({
    'id': function (index, attr) { return 'new_id-' + index },
    'name': function (index, attr) { return 'new_name-' + index }
});
```

This will change your input's id and name like this:

```
<tr>
    <td><input type="text" id="new_id-0" name="new_name-0"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><input type="text" id="new_id-0" name="new_name-1"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><input type="text" id="new_id-0" name="new_name-2"></td>
</tr>
```

You can find more info in [API docs for attr()](http://api.jquery.com/attr/#attr2).

Answer (score 1):

From [Looping and setting name and id in jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3479474)

```
$(function() {
    $('#table tr').each(function(index, element)
    {
       var e = $(element);
       e.find('td:eq(0)').text(index);
       var first = 'txtCollectionText' + index.toString();
       var second = 'txtLink' + index.toString();
       e.find('td:eq(1) input').attr({name: first, id: first});
       e.find('td:eq(2) input').attr({name: second, id: second});
    });
}
```

If placed inside a script tag, this code will automatically execute as soon as the document is finished being constructed by the browser. That's what the `$(function() {})` notation does -- it's shorthand for `$(document).bind('ready', function() {})`.